# Plone package to download or zip contents of a folder

Tags: plone, package

I am wondering if there is a package for Plone which would let an authenticated user to either zip the full contents of a folder or download its contents (files or pages) to the computer.

Comment: Another way: Enable Webdav and then Windows users can just drag and drop folders to their local computer using proper WebDav client.

Comment: I was thinking about webdav as well, but my environment has mac, win and linux users. I used webdav some years ago but I had to drop it because it wasn't too reliable.

Comment: That's very true. I think the world has moved to post-WebDAV era. Maybe on one day we can have HTML5 drag'and'drop where you simply pull an item out of Plone web page and drop it on your desktop.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for right now... :)

Comment: There's some packages that do this: Products.PloneFilesZip or collective.zipfiletransport. All are quite old and I'm not sure they still work but you'll probably find a way to export folder and files with them.
A totally different task is about exporting Plone pages.

Comment: I think that the question is within the topic of the tags chosen: "plone" and "packages". I found the answer below to be fully satisfactory. How can this be off topic if it was exactly what I was looking for? What topic should have been chosen instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ftw.zipexport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftw.zipexport/1.2.1)

It supports exporting files and folders by default. 
It's easy to extend since you can simply register your own ZipRepresentation (Check Readme).

Also a good point is, that the zip file is generated on the filesystem (not in RAM). This allows you to generate large files.

Comment: FTW guys are awesome! :-)